# Determine whether the function is a linear transformation:

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine whether the function is a linear transformation. Justify your answer.

$T: P_2 → P_2$, where 
$T(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2) = a_0 + a_1(x+1) + a_2(x+1)^2$

My thought process on solving this:
I know that in order to be a linear transformation, the following 2 conditions must be met:

1. $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$
2. $T(cu) = cT(u)$

I'm new to linear transformations, and I'm confused on how to set this up.

For instance, how do I know what $u$ and $v$ are?

Comment: $ \ u \ $ and $ \ v \ $ are sort of "dummy" variables:  in this case, you would choose two quadratic polynomials for use in the tests of the conditions.

Comment: Read "T(u+v) must equal T(u) + T(v) for all u and v in your space", etc.

Comment: u and v are quadratic polynomials.

Comment: first thing to check is always: $T(0)=0$.

Comment: notice, technically you also need to check $T: P_2 \rightarrow P_2$ however, it is obvious that the values of $T$ are actually in $P_2$ so it wasn't an issue for this problem. Usually the issue of "into" is not interesting, but it's there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u = a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2$ (some element of your space), $v = b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2$ (some other element of your space) and $c$ be some scalar. Show that your two conditions hold for *all* possible $a_0, a_1, a_2, b_0, b_1, b_2, c$. That is, for $T$ to be linear, these two conditions should hold no matter what $u$ (a vector), $v$ (a vector) and $c$ (a scalar) are.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the fact that $T(p(x))=p(x+1)$ for any polynomial
$p(x)$ in $P_2$.  Then you could observe that

1) $T(p(x)+q(x))=p(x+1)+q(x+1)=T(p(x))+T(q(x))$ and that

2) $T(c[p(x)])=c[p(x+1)]=c[T(p(x))]$ for any scalar c.